# Typescript: Creating a method on a class with args that are part of the class

Tags: typescript

I created a class and want to extract repeated logic into a method on the class to be re-used by other properties of the class.

```
class Card {
  protected readonly data: Data;
  protected readonly user: User;
  nameVal: string;
  addressVal: string[];

  constructor(raw_data: Data, user: User) {
    this.data = raw_data;
    this.user = user;
  }

  get name(): string {
    if (!this.nameVal) {
      this.nameVal = name_getter(this.data, this.user); // same parameters
    }
    return this.nameVal;
  }

  get address(): string[] {
    if (!this.addressVal) {
      this.addressVal = address_getter(this.data, this.user); // same parameters
    }
    return this.addressVal;
  }

  // I want to refactor the above logic and have it handled in a function like below
  // maybe getter type would be something like this: 
  // type FieldValueGetter = (data: Data, user: User) => any;
  getFieldValue(getter: FieldValueGetter, field: ?) { // Is there a way to define field type? 
    if(!field) {
      this.field = getter(this.data, this.user);
    }
    return this.field;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how I can define the type for the field parameter for getFieldValue method as the value of the field would differ by field, but the common factor is that the field would be part of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

> keyof

```
function getter(data:Data, user:User, field: string){
// your logic here.
}
class Card {
    protected readonly data: Data;
    protected readonly user: User;

    field: string = '';
    field2: number = 0;

    constructor(raw_data: Data, user: User) {
        this.data = raw_data;
        this.user = user;
    }

    getFieldValue<T>(getter: FieldValueGetter, field: keyof this): T {
        if (!field) {
            this[field] = getter(this.data, this.user, field);
        }
        return this[field] as any as  T;
    }
}

const card = new Card({}, {});
card.getFieldValue<string>(getter, 'field');
card.getFieldValue<number>(getter, 'field2');
```

Comment: Thank You! Ooh, `keyof` works! But, now when I want to reuse this `getFieldValue` method say within `get address()`, since each of the fields would have different output values, I would need to cast the type on the output of `getFieldValue` e.g. `get subtitles(): string[] {return <string[]>this.fieldValueGetter(address_getter, 'addressVal');}`. Can I do better?

Comment: @PBandJen, I made an edit, in my answer, is this what you are looking for? 
Since the key value is dynamic, the default value would be any, but you can perform this adjustment with a few extra parameters to handle everything in the get function, and return a typed value to whoever calls it. 
I hope it helps you :).

Comment: @PBandJen,
In TS there is a way to extract the type, but it only works for simple types.
Example:
`typeof 'gustavo' returns correct 'string';`
`typeof [''] returns 'object' and not 'Array'`